# #import breaks build in Xcode with forward class reference

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, header-files

I subclasssed one of my view controllers and try to #import the header file of the new class in one of the other header files.

As soon as I include that #import, the entire build goes crazy, with errors in many classes, such as these:

- Cannot find protocol declaration...
- Cannot find interface declaration...
- Unknown type name...
- Incompatible pointer types...

These errors are all in files that are not directly related to the new class, it's superclass, or to the file with the import.

As soon as I remove the #import, the build is fine.

Here is the subclass definition, in the files ReadOnlySearchVC.h and ReadOnlySearchVC.m. As can be seen, this is just the template created by Xcode when I initially created the new class.

**Header file of the subclass:**

```
#import "AdvancedSearchFormVC.h"

@interface ReadOnlySearchVC : AdvancedSearchFormVC

@end
```

and **Code file of the subclass:**

```
#import "ReadOnlySearchVC.h"

@interface ReadOnlySearchVC ()

@end

@implementation ReadOnlySearchVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Here is the header file, where I import the subclass ReadOnlySearchVC in the class ResultsHeaderView

**Header file of a referencing class:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ReadOnlySearchVC.h"  // this is the offending line
@class SearchTerms;
@class DataInterfaceObject;
@class MapController;


@protocol resultsHeaderDelegate 

- (void) collapseSection:(NSInteger) section;
- (void) expandSection:(NSInteger) section;

@optional
- (void) deleteSection:(NSInteger) section;
- (void) headerDeleteButtonWillShow;
- (void) headerDeleteButtonDidHide;

@end

@interface ResultsHeaderView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

...  the rest of the file ...
```

The second line, `#import "ReadOnlySearchVC.h"` is creating the problem.

I updated Xcode from 4.3.1 to 4.3.3 and it didn't change. I did a clean build, and it didn't change.

I can only imagine there is some kind of circular reference, but I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Now this is a little strange, because I did have it working initially, with just some skeleton code, but including what is shown above. At some point as I added the rest of the design to the two classes shown above, it broke, and I'm not sure why. Stripping it back to these basics  still demonstrates the problem.

Does anyone have an idea what I am looking at?

Comment: circular dependency, yup - most likely. would need to follow the `#include` trail (e.g. what is included in `#import "AdvancedSearchFormVC.h"`? and so on). the problem may be clearer if you examine the preprocessed output.

Comment: How do I examine the preprocessed output. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: in Xc4 a) navigate to the `.m` file b) select `Product > Generate Output > Preprocessed File`. then you will see how the compiler sees it, with all preprocessed includes in order.